# Sending video as response in django

Tags: django, video, response

How to send a video mp4 file as a response in django? I don't want to embed in a video or object tags of html, but want to send the mp4 itself. Can anyone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Generally you don't want to do this; it's better to redirect to a non-Django server to [serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production), with e.g. [`django.shortcuts.redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) -- it'll be faster, more memory-efficient, and probably more secure. But of course sometimes that's not convenient. This should work:

```
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

file = FileWrapper(open('path/to/video.mp4', 'rb'))
response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='video/mp4')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my_video.mp4'
return response
```

The `FileWrapper` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.util.FileWrapper)) is used so that too much data isn't sent at once, since Python file objects iterate a line at a time, and `\n` characters presumably aren't especially common in mp4s. (Sending too much means that the webserver can't send the file as it's read off the hard drive but instead has to wait for long awkwardly-spaced increments.)

Note that although I don't see this noted in the documentation anywhere, the file [does get closed when it's done with](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py#L676).

Comment: Thanks Dougal its working, but its downloading with i hit the url in the browser. I dont want that, i want the mp4 to play in the browser itself. Moreover, its a small video file about 10 mb, so i dont want to use any other non-Django server.

Comment: Try taking out the Content-Disposition line, that might help. But if this is a production site you should already be serving your CSS and images and so on outside of Django anyway....

Comment: I tried taking out the Content-Disposition line, i'm getting an error called "error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"

Comment: Does that happen reproducibly when the content-disposition line is commented out and not when it isn't? That seems like [this problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/UZi-nhBD1Tw), which is just that the dev server can only do one thing at a time.